Role-Authorization for ASP.NET Core Identity methods in ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm in the process of trying to learn both ASP.NET Core Web API and also ASP.NET Core Identity. I've seen that ASP.NET Core Identity has now been integrated into web APIs as part of .NET 8 through MapIdentityAPI.
I am trying to develop an application that will make use of my API however I want to restrict the registration process to authorized users only that are in a certain role. This is to make it so that only admin users of the application can register a new user.
I am unsure how to go about this though as the Identity methods are automatically generated by implementing ASP.NET Core Identity so I can't go and put an Authorize attribute on them to restrict the access. Is there any advice on how I could go about this?
Many thanks
I have attempted implementing ASP.NET Core Identity with ASP.NET Core Web API in .NET 8 already which has been successful through testing with Swagger however I am unable to find the methods so I can put an authorize attribute on them. I am making use of an API as it will be the connector for a .NET MAUI front end application.

Do you mean you want to custom the route to make just administrator role user could access the register?

If you just want add role for the register route, I suggest you could try to create a custome mapidentityapi method.
Its soucres codes is this:
So you just need copy them and create and modify the MapIdentityApi method's register like below:
         // NOTE: We cannot inject UserManager<TUser> directly because the TUser generic parameter is currently unsupported by RDG.
        // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47338
        routeGroup.MapPost("/register", async Task<Results<Ok, ValidationProblem>>
            ([FromBody] RegisterRequest registration, HttpContext context, [FromServices] IServiceProvider sp) =>
        {
            var userManager = sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();

            if (!userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"xxxx requires a user store with email support.");
            }

            var userStore = sp.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<TUser>>();
            var emailStore = (IUserEmailStore<TUser>)userStore;
            var email = registration.Email;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || !_emailAddressAttribute.IsValid(email))
            {
                return CreateValidationProblem(IdentityResult.Failed(userManager.ErrorDescriber.InvalidEmail(email)));
            }

            var user = new TUser();
            await userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, email, CancellationToken.None);
            await emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, email, CancellationToken.None);
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registration.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return CreateValidationProblem(result);
            }

            await SendConfirmationEmailAsync(user, userManager, context, email);
            return TypedResults.Ok();
        }).RequireAuthorization("Admin");

